# LoadApplication(new App()) throws error on IOS! Working fine on Android Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My application is working as desired on Android but when I try to run it on ios (Emulator/device) it throws Null reference exception.

Here is the code in App.xaml.cs

```
public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (true)
            {
                if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
                {
                    do something
                }
                MainPage = new MyApp.MenuItems();
            }
            else
            {
                MainPage = new MyApp.MainPage();
            }

        }
```

Please help as app is fully ready for android and something going wrong with ios.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question with sufficient and specific information to describe your problem.

Comment: App should not have any InitializeComponents call as it doesn't have a page. Was this code generated?

Comment: Hi Sky! When you get a chance, please edit your question and add the full stacktrace so that we can see the error!

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
switch(Device.RuntimePlatform)
{

     case Device.iOS:
          MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MyApp.MainPage());
          break;
     case Device.Android:
          MainPage = new MyApp.MainPage();
          break;
}
```

may be it's help you

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could explain, *why* would this help, why does  iOS need that extra code?

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that you have installed connectivity plugin into ios project too?

Comment: Yes. But the thing is application is not going to any breakpoint in forms (PCL) project. So not even able to debug!

Comment: do you tried clean the project, and rebuild solution?